# How to save a file in LocalStorage?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an `ObservableCollection <T>`. I want to insert the various elements in it and then save the newly created file in `LocalStorage`. How can I do that?

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db"), true);
await conn.CreateTableAsync<Musei>();
var Dbase = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db");
var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Dbase, true);

var query = await con.Table<Musei>().ToListAsync();
ObservableCollection<Musei> favMusei = new ObservableCollection<Musei>();

if (query.Count > 0)
{
    favMusei.Clear();

    foreach (Musei museifav in query)
    {
        favMusei.Add(museifav);            
    }
}
```

Comment: what problems and or issues are you having when you run your existing code.. please provide more information

Comment: I would like to save 'favmusei' in Local Storage

Comment: that's nice..but what issues are you having when running your existing code.. don't just say `I would like to save favmusei in local storage` debug the code and tell us where the break down is happening..

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from looking into serialization. Whether that's an option for you will depend on what `Musei`  objects comprise of though. Basic rule is data can be serialized an deserialized pretty easily, behaviour (particularly event handlers and delegates) can't (or not safely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a json file to store in the memory. JSON is a light weight message exchange format and is widely used. You have to do some slight modifications in the code if you want some different file format.

Your collection would be serialized to the memory at the time of saving and has to be deserialized when reading it back from memory.

Add your own generic implementation of the collection. To create your situation i'm using a simple `ObservableCollection<int>`. And don't forget to initialize the collection to some meaningful values, here i'm using the default constructor initialization.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Windows.Storage;

//Add your own generic implementation of the collection
//and make changes accordingly
private ObservableCollection<int> temp;

private string file = "temp.json";

private async void saveToFile()
{
    //add your items to the collection
    temp = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<int>));

    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, temp);
    }
}

private async Task getFormFile()
{
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<int>));

    try
    {
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(file))
        {
            temp = (ObservableCollection<int>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        //if some error is caught while reading data from the file then initializing 
        //the collection to default constructor instance is a good choice 
        //again it's your choice and may differ in your scenario
        temp = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }
}
```

To add some functionality to the code you can also have an `ensureDataLoaded()` function which would ensure that the data has been read from the JSON file.

```
public async Task ensureDataLoaded()
{
    if (temp.Count == 0)
        await getFormFile();

    return;
}
```

Before using the global variable `temp` (having the `ObservableCollection`) call the `ensureDataLoaded` function. It would avoid some unnecessary `NullPointerExceptions`.